# How to make google navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation

so i tried quite a lot of techniques but none of them have worked. I'm new to HTML, just learning it college and trying to make a **google-like navigation bar**. The issue i have is to center the right links. I tried `vertical-align`, `position: relative/absolute` with `top:50%` but it still does not work. Any suggestions?

Current code

CSS

```
nav{border-bottom:2px solid black; height:60px;}
        #right{float:right;}
        #left{float:left;}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
    <div id="left">Test (Will be an image in the future)</div>
    <div id="right">Test</div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: a good way to figure this out is go to the google home page (if in chrome) and right click on the navbar and select the option `inspect element` or, just hit f12, but that doesn't target a spot in the HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add the `line-height:60px` to your rules for `nav`:

```
nav {
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U6bBf/)**

Comment: does the line height work for images as well? Also thanks so much works just as i wanted it to :)

Comment: If you mean like this, http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U6bBf/1/, then you'd just need to also add a CSS rule for the images.

Comment: And i bounced into another issue... http://jsfiddle.net/sPY7B/
How would i go about making the left border in li stretch from all the way top to the bottom of the nav? I tried setting the height of the li to 60px with no results

Comment: For the li, change to display:inline-block.

Comment: Correct ones again, thank you very much. Still have a lot to learn :(

Answer (score 1):

Navigation bars are usually made with linked lists. There are plenty of tutorials for these online, you can find an easy example [here](http://www.cssnewbie.com/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/#.UweT2_ldVEM).

Also bear in mind that `nav` is a HTML5 element, and might not render correctly in all browsers.

Comment: IK they are, but i was just trying to get the alignment right first, then i would put in the content. Thanks for contribution though 
:)

Comment: I use Chrome so it should work for me just right, but if i was to use it on lets say ie8 should i just use div with id nav for example?

Comment: @LittleB0Y Sure, it's all about how you style it. Like I mentioned before, linked lists are more commonly used, but if done right `div` can achieve the same results.

Comment: I used both ul and div for this case, i think it should work on every browser. http://jsfiddle.net/5N3CA/
Also my proff says to use the latest tags from HTML5 but what i got from your statement is that its better to use the older tags that are still supported in HTML 5 right? Just for the sake of ppl with older browsers?

Comment: @LittleB0Y In an ideal world, every user in the world would keep up with updates and use the latest version of their browsers all the time. However, in the real world this is obviously not true, so it's not that it's "better" to keep using the older tags (but not so far as to use deprecated elements of course), but that it should be taken into account because some people out there still use older browsers. There are other options, like using scripts or JS libraries designed to support HTML5 in older browsers, but it's all about what you want to do.

Comment: Didn't take js in college just yet so ima stick to supported by html5 older tags :) Thanks for help